# Detect Websocket disconnection in Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-websocket

I have an Integration flow based on a WebSocketInboundChannelAdapter, configured as below.

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow integrationFlow() {
  StandardWebSocketClient client = new StandardWebSocketClient();
  ClientWebSocketContainer container = new ClientWebSocketContainer(client, url);
  WebSocketInboundChannelAdapter adapter = new WebSocketInboundChannelAdapter(container);
  return IntegrationFlow.from(adapter).handle(m -> m.getPayload()).get();
}
```

How can I detect a disconnection and reconnect to the same URL?

Answer (score 0):

One approach to go around with this is implement a **ApplicationListener** that listen for **SessionDisconnectEvent**.

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.integration.websocket.event.WebSocketSessionConnectEvent;
import org.springframework.integration.websocket.event.WebSocketSessionDisconnectEvent;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketSession;

@Component
public class WebSocketReconnectHandler implements ApplicationListener<WebSocketSessionDisconnectEvent> {

    private final ClientWebSocketContainer container;
    private final String url;

    public WebSocketReconnectHandler(ClientWebSocketContainer container, String url) {
        this.container = container;
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(WebSocketSessionDisconnectEvent event) {
        WebSocketSession session = event.getSession();
        if (session.isOpen()) {
            // WebSocket session disconnected; initiate a reconnect
            try {
                container.doStop();
                // Perform any additional cleanup or logging if needed
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Reconnect after a delay (e.g., 5 seconds)
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

            // Re-create and start the WebSocket container
            container.setUri(url);
            container.doStart();

            // You may want to log or perform additional actions here
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, we create a custom **WebSocketReconnectHandler** that listens for **WebSocketSessionDisconnectEvent** events. When a disconnect event occurs, the handler performs the following:

1. Validate the WebSocket session is still open.
2. Stops the WebSocket container.
3. Waits for a delay before attempting to reconnect (you can adjust the delay as needed).
4. Reconfigures and starts the WebSocket container with the same URL.

HTH.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. I wasn't aware of the WebSocketSessionDisconnectEvent. I'll give it a try.